# Extract text between multilevel repetitive xml tags using Php

Tags: php, xml, regex, data-extraction

I am trying to extract text between Multilevel XML tags.

This is the data file 
    `<eSearchResult>
    <Count>7117</Count>
    <RetMax>10</RetMax>
    <RetStart>0</RetStart>
    <QueryKey>1</QueryKey>
    <WebEnv>
    NCID_1_457044331_130.14.22.215_9001_1401819380_1399850995
    </WebEnv>
    <IdList>
    <Id>24887359</Id>
    <Id>24884828</Id>
    <Id>24884718</Id>
    <Id>24884479</Id>
    <Id>24882343</Id>
    <Id>24879340</Id>
    <Id>24871662</Id>
    <Id>24870721</Id>
    <Id>24864115</Id>
    <Id>24863809</Id>
    </IdList>
    <TranslationSet/>
    <TranslationStack>
    <TermSet>
    <Term>BRCA1[tiab]</Term>
    .
    .
    .
    </TranslationStack>
    </eSearchResult>`

 
I just want to extract the ten ids between `<ID></ID>` tags enclosed inside `<IdList></IdList>`.
Regex gets me just the first value out of the ten. 
    `preg_match_all('~<Id>(.+?)<\/Id>~', $temp_str, $pids)`
the xml data is stored in the $temp_Str variable and I am trying to get the values stored in $pids
Any other suggestions to go about this ?

Comment: Can you add the php code that has the regex?

Comment: @mrk added in the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using preg_match_all (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), I've included a regex that matches on digits within an `<Id>` tag.  The trickiest part (I think), is in the foreach loop, where I iterate `$out[1]`.  This is because, from the URL above,

> Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern
>   matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

```
preg_match_all('/<Id>\s*(\d+)\s*<\/Id>/',
   "<eSearchResult>
<Count>7117</Count>
<RetMax>10</RetMax>
<RetStart>0</RetStart>
<QueryKey>1</QueryKey>
<WebEnv>
NCID_1_457044331_130.14.22.215_9001_1401819380_1399850995
</WebEnv>
<IdList>
<Id>24887359</Id>
<Id>24884828</Id>
<Id>24884718</Id>
<Id>24884479</Id>
<Id>24882343</Id>
<Id>24879340</Id>
<Id>24871662</Id>
<Id>24870721</Id>
<Id>24864115</Id>
<Id>24863809</Id>
</IdList>
<TranslationSet/>
<TranslationStack>
<TermSet>
<Term>BRCA1[tiab]</Term>
</TranslationStack>
</eSearchResult>",
$out,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
foreach ($out[1] as $o){
      echo $o;
      echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: If I want to search for someother tag between which there are alpha numeric multi line sentences, How will I tweak this regex?

Comment: Assuming WebEnv looks like this: `<WebEnv>
NCID_1_457044331_130.14.22.215_9001_1401819380_1399850995
NCID_2_222222
</WebEnv>`, then the regex, `'/<WebEnv>\s*([0-9A-Za-z\.\_\n]+)\s*<\/WebEnv>/s'` will do the trick.  The key is the ending '/s' modifier to switch to "single line" mode. Read more about regex modifiers here:  http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: No need for the `U` modifier - its just slowing down the match and confusing things. That, and its never needed. In other words: _Never use the `U` ungreedy flag!_

Answer (score 1):

You should use php's xpath capabilities, as explained here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp

Example:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("searchdata.xml");
$result = $xml->xpath("IdList/Id");
print_r($result);
?>
```

XPath is flexible, can be used conditionally, and is supported in a wide variety of other languages as well.  It is also more readable and easier to write than regex, as you can construct conditional queries without using lookaheads.

Comment: The data I have is in a file pointer. Its retrieved from a online search from Pubmed website. All my xml data is in a variable. Is there a way I can use a variable in the xpath functionality? @stephen

Comment: @Vignesh as a disclaimer, I don't have PHP setup on this machine, so I won't be able to fully test these code snippets.  According to the documentation for simplexml_load_file you should be able to pass in a URL to the xml file.  Please look here: https://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `(?:\<IdList\>|\G)\s*\<Id\>(\d+)\<\/Id\>` with `g` option
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aE6iA0)

Comment: `$pattern = "(?:\<IdList\>|\G)\s*\<Id\>(\d+)\<\/Id\>";
 preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);`
This gives me unexpected ? error

Answer (score 0):

Do not use PCRE to parse XML. Here are CSS Selectors and even better Xpath to fetch parts of an XML DOM.

If you want any `Id` element in the first `IdList` of the `eSearchResult`

`/eSearchResult/IdList[1]/Id`

As you can see Xpath "knows" about the actual structure of an XML document. PCRE does not.

You need to create an Xpath object for a DOM document

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$result = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/eSearchResult/IdList[1]/Id') as $id) [
  $result[] = trim($id->nodeValue);
}
var_dump($id);
```